# Can't use python on mac because of xcode

Tags: xcode, macos

I installed xcode to see if I could use it but I am unable to accept the licence agreement because I do not have admin privileges. Because of this things like python and git can't be used. I also can not uninstall xcode because I do not have admin privileges. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: How does Xcode stop you from using python?  If I type "which python", I get "/usr/bin/python".  That's not something Xcode controls.  Same for git.  (I suggest you talk to whoever *does* have admin privs.  I can't imagine trying to do development on a Mac where I couldn't access admin functions!)

Comment: Since I have not accepted the licensing agreement I get this:
`You have not agreed to the Xcode license agreements. You must agree to both license agreements below in order to use Xcode.

Hit the Return key to view the license agreements at '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Resources/English.lproj/License.rtf'`
and as I said Im unable to accept the license agreements

Comment: I have noticed that this happens with python3 but not python.

Comment: If you type `echo $PATH` in the Terminal, what does it show?

Comment: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`